# StringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString with options issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I want to replace occurrences of the strings of the following format with some other strings. This operation should be happen in a for loop.

Here fullString looks something like this

```
There are some other things ... Child_name_13 and Child_name_12     there are some other things ...... Child_name_1 some other things ... Child_name_12 some other things.. Child_name_6 some other things ... Child_name_7
```

What I want to do is, replace the "Child_name_1", "Child_name_12", "Child_name_7" and etc with relevant child names returns from the arrOfChildren.

My approach as follows.

```
for(int i=0; i<[arrOfChildren count]; i++){
    NSString *strChildName = [[arrOf15Children objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];

    fullString = [fullString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"child_name_%d",i+1] withString:strChildName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [fullString length])];
}
```

The issue is, I am getting the output something like this **(Lets say child names as Ben, Randy, Amil, Sanj, Paul, Mark, Ayen, Sid, Don, Yun, Xun, Xin, Nik, Jack)**

```
There are some other things ... Ben3 and Ben2     there are some other things ...... Ben some other things ... Ben2 some other things..  Mark some other things ... Ayen
```

But I want it to be like this

```
There are some other things ...Nik and Xin  there are some other things ...... Ben some other things ... Xin some other things.. Mark some other things ... Ayen
```

I hope, you will get the issue.

Comment: Check my answer, it could perform way better than regexps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Regular expression solves your problem to take entire string we have to use this **\\bchild_name_%d\\b**

Check the follwing code

```
NSArray *arrOfChildren = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six", @"seven", @"eight", @"nine", @"ten", @"leven", @"twe", @"thirt", @"fourten", @"fiftee", nil];

NSString *fullString = @"Child_name_1 Child_name_2 Child_name_3 Child_name_4 Child_name_5 Child_name_6 Child_name_7 Child_name_8 Child_name_9 Child_name_10 Child_name_11 Child_name_12  Child_name_13 Child_name_14 Child_name_15  ";

for(int i=0; i<[arrOfChildren count]; i++){
    NSString *strChildName = [arrOfChildren objectAtIndex:i];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\bchild_name_%d\\b",i+1] options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

    fullString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:fullString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [fullString length]) withTemplate:strChildName];

}

NSLog(@"full stirng %@", fullString);
```

- inclue this in your code

for(int i=0; i<[arrOfChildren count]; i++) {

```
NSString *strChildName = [[arrOf15Children objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\bchild_name_%d\\b",i+1] options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

fullString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:fullString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [fullString length]) withTemplate:strChildName];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to:
`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"child_name_%d",i+1]`

because a *Child_name_1* will match a *Child_name_13*.

There are different solutions to this problem.

1) Multipass substitution:
first replace items matching numbers greater equal 10, then the remaining ones.

```
for(int i=9; i<[arrOfChildren count]; i++){
    NSString *strChildName = [[arrOf15Children objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];

    fullString = [fullString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"child_name_%d",i+1] withString:strChildName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [fullString length])];
}
for(int i=0; i<max(9,[arrOfChildren count]); i++){
    NSString *strChildName = [[arrOf15Children objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];

    fullString = [fullString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"child_name_%d",i+1] withString:strChildName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [fullString length])];
}
```

2) Much more robust would be using **regular expressions** (`NSRegularExpression`) with an expression like `[...] expression = @"child_name_[0-9]+[^0-9]"`.

Regular expressions are a bit tricky, but investing in learning them will give you 'superpowers' on Stringhandling!

Comment: thanks for the help. I could do it using using regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Matching by unknown number of digits will get you multiple matches. 'Child_name_10' does have 'Child_name_1' in it so by searching for 'Child_name_1' you will get multiple matches.

You can match by 'Child_name_1 ' (note space) but then you have to remember to add space to name you are replacing with. Or you can insert leading zeroes in 'Child_name_x' strings (so 'Child_name_01' instead of 'Child_name_1' etc.) and then change your stringWithFormat to:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"child_name_%02d",i+1]
```

If you have more than 99 children, do the same but for three digits (so %03d and 'Child_name_001') etc.

Comment: adding zeros wont solve the issue. because 'Child_name_01' and 'Child_name_010' again be the same??? Isn't there any standard way to do this like adding some options to the search criteria ...

Comment: @sajaz with this format it will be 'Child_name_10' not 'Child_name_010'. Leading zeroes only come into play where there is not enough digits in the number.

Answer (score 0):

You had better change to [NSString stringWithFormat:@" child_name_%d ",i+1] , with the blank space ,you can separate the prefix problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the **NSRegularExpression** can do you favour:

```
NSString *string = @"Child_name_1 and Child_name_13 are friends";
NSArray *nameArray = @[@"Tom", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11", @"Jerry"];

for (int i = 0; i < [nameArray count]; i++) {
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\bChild_name_%d\\b", i + 1] options:0 error:nil];
    if (regex != nil) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *firstMatch = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
        if (firstMatch) {
            NSRange resultRange = [firstMatch rangeAtIndex:0];
            string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:resultRange withString:[nameArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"result:%@", string);
```

Also you can have a look to **NSScanner** :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Just made up super simple solution. If you know that in the string won't contain any `child_name` with index more then count of names you have, i.e. you have 5 names in your names array and in the string there could be maximum child_name5 and child_name6+ are for sure absent.

**You just invert the direction you iterate you names**:

```
// only changed for statements, the rest is your code unchanged
for(int i=[arrOfChildren count]-1; i>=0; i--){
    NSString *strChildName = [[arrOf15Children objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];

    fullString = [fullString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"child_name_%d",i+1] withString:strChildName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [fullString length])];
}
```

So you replace all `child_name15`, then all `child_name14` and so on till `child_name0`. That's how we're spoiled with all this top level powerful facilities, that we forget how coding should be done.

**Old answer:**

You just need a regular expression for that. You find all matches and replace them with desired names.
Example of a regular expression which might work:

```
child_name[0-9]*
```

You find all matches, for example, via NSRegularExpression and replace them with appropriate values using something else. Other solution could be creating more complex regular expression with groups and use them to achieve what you want in a more elegant way.